# ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED in oreo

Tags: android, android-package-managers

in my application i want to do operation on newly installed app at real time. Previously we are using broadcast receiver for this. But now as per new google policy we have to change target sdk version to 26. And system-sent implicit broadcasts (ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) we can't use if application is not present in memory.

My requirement is for real time so don't want to use polling using jobScheduler because there also job will start only after 15 min.

So what we can do this to know whether new app is installed or not at real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I had resolve this by using foreground service. I had called foreground service which keeps the broadcastReceiver alive, which was registered at runtime instead of manifest. Thanks